# C# static field, non thread, race condition

Tags: c#, static

I was wondering what gets initialized first in following example
`A.a` or `B.b`

```cs
class A {
    static int a = methodA();
    static int methodA() { return 5; }
}
class B {
    static int b = methodB();
    static int methodB() { return A.a; } // here is the problem: `b` depends on `a`
}
```

If `a`, then all is fine
`methodA` returns 5, which is stored to `a`. Then `methodB` retrieves the value of `a` and returns it.

But if `b` is first, it gets garbage value from `a`, and, after that, `a` is initialized to 5.

Comment: Did you try it? Set some breakpoints and try different combinations...best way to learn. You should find that the first time a static class is accessed it will initialize it and run the static constructor (if it exists). So if `B.b` is called and `A` hasn't been accessed yet, it should initialize `A` right then and there.

Comment: @David784 I have tried it. It succeeded. That does not mean it will always work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In looking at the c# language specification, I don't see how there is any race condition. This is a quote from the section on [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-constructors):

> To initialize a new closed class type, first a new set of static fields (Static and instance fields) for that particular closed type is created. Each of the static fields is initialized to its default value (Default values). Next, the static field initializers (Static field initialization) are executed for those static fields. Finally, the static constructor is executed.

What is happening in the code example above is "static field initialization."  The spec lists that as happening immediately after default value initialization, and before any static constructor is called.

Take the following code as an example:

```
using System;

namespace console1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("begin main()");
            var x = B.b;
            Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}");
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        static B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("static B()");
        }
        public static int b = methodB();
        static int methodB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"initial B.b value {b}");
            Console.WriteLine("B.methodB()");
            return A.a;
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("static A()");
        }
        public static int a = methodA();
        static int methodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A.methodA()");
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

The console output of this is:

```
begin main()
initial B.b value 0
B.methodB()
A.methodA()
static A()
static B()
x = 5
```

This bears out what the spec says, in the following steps:

- class B is accessed first, and static field initialization of variable b begins.
- default value can be read for B.b (0, as @Blindy says), before the static field initialization completes.
- it encounters a call to class A, which hasn't been initialized yet.
- it pauses initialization of class B and starts initialization of class A
- static field initialization of variable a occurs, setting the value to 5 (You could also view the default value of 0 for this property before the static field initialization completes, but I believe the only place this could occur is inside `methodA` before the `return`)
- the static constructor is then called.
- initialization of class B resumes
- static constructor in class B is called.
- finally the value of `5` is returned for `B.b`, as desired/expected.

There doesn't seem to be any possibility of a race condition here, since the first time a class with static members is referenced, whatever is currently happening is immediately paused and the class is fully initialized.

(At least in single-threaded code which is what OP is asking about. My initial thought is that multi-threaded code would also introduce no race conditions, but I couldn't say for sure)

Comment: They are not static classes (that is another thing). Also, question. As I understand, when C# initializes class, it tries to initialize it whole (default value, field init, static constr), and only stops when other class is referenced?

Comment: Thank you, you're right I had gotten sloppy with my language, calling them static classes, rather than regular classes with static members. I've edited my answer. Yes, that's my understanding as well. It would be the same with any external dependency I think, whether it was (as in this case) the initialization of a class, or a function call, or whatever...it will stop/pause to handle that external call/initialization, and then resume when it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is a race condition in the language specification itself. Either one will be run first, and you have no control over it. You either pray the specific compilation that linked your code, as well as the JIT that's running your code got it "right" (from your point of view), or you simply write correct, deterministic code.

One option to get rid of this is to use one static constructor to initialize the dependent static variables sequentially.

> it gets garbage value from `a`

That will never happen by the way, the field will be either zero-initialized or initialized by your code.

Comment: There is no race, static constructors run in order, see [15.12 of the ECMA-334 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2731%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C55%2C570%2C0%5D) as well as [15.5.6.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2453%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C55%2C723%2C0%5D). There is only a race when there is a circular reference, which there is not here, or where both fields refer to a ...

Comment: ... common field of another type, and neither of the first two types have static constructors

Comment: Who is upvoting these random comments? What possible meaning do you attribute to "in order" when classes can be in different files and they get linked together? What order? Your order? Well good thing C# is a mind reader, Charlie face here guarantees this code will always work as expected!

Comment: When I said "in order" I didn't mean textual order, that's only relevant within a single non-`partial` class. I meant that in the example there is no way for `B.b` to be anything other than 5, because its initializer runs when referenced the first time, in turn referencing and initializing `A.a`. There is simply no way for it to be anything else, not even 0, because there is no circular reference.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the document, page 334 (15.12) has an example pretty similar to mine (though it is about circular reference), but it shows exactly what would happen in my situation.